# how to sign and align a .apk file

Tags: java, android

I have created an app and i want it to submit in the android market site. I know that for submission process i have to change the app to be an .apk file

I had made my app to be an .apk file by selecting Export unsigned package from android tools.

But how to sign and align the project. Pls give me the steps and instructions to be followed.

Answer (score 1):

The following gives step by step instructions:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to a command line prompt and get to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\jarsigner.exe

Run the following command :

jarsigner -verbose -keystore "[PATH TO YOUR KEY STORE]\YourKey.keystore" "[PATH TO YOUR APK FILE]MyAndroidApp-amz.apk" alias_name"

That should sign your file.